# JSQCoreDataKit: Use of undeclared type 'SaveResult' despite finding the definition of the type when clicking "Go to definition"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I am using the framework [JSQCoreDataKit](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQCoreDataKit).
I've installed it successfully:

[image]

In one of the files, it is used as follows:

```
import JSQCoreDataKit

    func saveChanges(completion: @escaping (SaveResult) -> Swift.Void) {
        stack.mainContext.performAndWait {
            saveContext(self.stack.mainContext, wait: true, completion: { (result) in
                completion(result)
            })
        }
    }
```

That function definition throws these errors:

> Use of undeclared type 'SaveResult'

When I right-click on `SaveResult`, and go to definition:
[image]
It opens this file:
[image]
So I find its definition:

```
extension NSManagedObjectContext {

    /// Describes a child managed object context.
    public typealias ChildContext = NSManagedObjectContext

    /// Describes the result type for saving a managed object context.
    public typealias SaveResult = Result<NSManagedObjectContext, Error> 
    //...
```

So I really do not see why am I getting that error if the Xcode can route me to its definition.

Answer (score 0):

`typealias SaveResult` is in the scope of `NSManagedObjectContext`, not defined globally.

use `NSManagedObjectContext.SaveResult`, instead of `SaveResult`.

---

It is OK

```
func saveChanges(completion: @escaping (NSManagedObjectContext.SaveResult) -> Swift.Void) {
   
    }
```

---

This is also OK,

in the same file

```
public typealias SaveResult = Result<NSManagedObjectContext, Error>

extension NSManagedObjectContext {}
```